# Script that outputs all DLLs used by exe

Tags: python, powershell, dll, cmd, exe

In cmd the line

```
tasklist /m /fi "imagename eq xxxxx.exe" > output.txt
```

will output the DLLs used by all processes to one file.

How can I separate the output to multiple txt files, each file contains the name of the process the the DLL used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
Get-Process |
    ForEach-Object {
        $procName = $_.Name
        Get-Process -InputObject $_ -Module -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Export-Csv ".\$procName.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
```