# How to pipeline variable cmdlets in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I want to parameterize a Powershell pipeline by inserting a pipeline step from a parameter like in the following simplified example.

```
param (
    $path,
    $dataset,
    $processor
)

$datasetProcessor = Get-Command 'Convert-Noop'
if ( $processor.Keys -contains $dataset.Name ) {
    $datasetProcessor = $Processor[$dataset.Name]
}

Read-Dataset $dataset `
| $datasetProcessor `
| Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

This results in the error

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Maybe it will work using Invoke-Expression, but then i would be no longer able to use the debugger.

What approach may work?

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: I am guessing this error is occuring where you have `Read-Dataset ...`.  Try removing the backticks and move the leave the pipe character to the end of the line instead.  PowerShell automatically looks on the next line for the rest of the pipeline.  See this old answer of mine to see what I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406523/script-that-outputs-all-dlls-used-by-exe/50407130#50407130.  The indenting is optional, but can make the code more readable.

Comment: Side, note: if `$processor` is a hashtable like it looks it is, then `$processor.ContainsKey($dataset.Name)` is better than `$processor.Keys -contains $dataset.Name`.  Hashtables are designed for quick lookups this way, while the `-contains` operator is going to scan the entire array of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a scriptblock (or a command returned from get-command) as a pipeline element.  That's an expression.

To use the scriptblock, add a & in front of it.

```
Read-Dataset $dataset `
| & $datasetProcessor `
| Export-Csv $path -NoTypeInformation
```

here's an example using built-in cmdlets:

```
$sort=get-command sort-object

get-childitem | & $sort -property Length -descending
```

Comment: I'd also remove the continuation characters as @boxdog suggests, but those shouldn't keep it from working.